# Autogenerate Timestamp as Id for database?

Tags: java, database, timestamp

`@Id` attribute has in general the ability to auto generate database primary key ids.
I'd like to have a timestamp is Id (I can ensure that there will be no 2 same timestamps).

Would you set the timestamp directly to the property of the variable, or initilize it within the constructor, or pass it as parameter in the constructor?

```
@Entity
public class MyDomain implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());

    public MyDomain() {
        this.timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
    }

    public MyDomain(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

What would you chose, and why?

Comment: For one thing, Java only uses milliseconds as timestamps; most DBs default to nanoseconds (or only seconds) - having mismatches between app/db is a good way to lose something.  Limiting your DB to id's by timestamp is a good way to limit your db throughput, if you get a lot of requests suddenly.  Use timestamps to record date/time information.  Use an id (usually integer) for uniquely identifying rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not do that, use timestamp as an ID. The id filed should not have any business values at all(at least in my experience so far), I would add another timestamp row. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using a timestamp as the primary key. It's clumsy for a unique column. Also do you really want to be using a cumbersome field like that as a foreign key in your other tables?

If this timestamp genuinely needs to be unique then you should probably put timestamp in its own field and use a unique constraint.

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"timestamp"})})
public class MyDomain implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "timestamp")
  public Timestamp timestamp;
}
```